# Remove the text in a ping token after a number in ping statistics to use

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, windows-xp, ping

I'm doing a simple ping bandwidth test in batch to get speed in kb/s and I've run into a problem with the ms trailer after the average round trip time 123ms. The batch can't deal with the letters in the number token and it has no space to set another token with. I've looked at several solutions using `delims=` but did not success. I'm stuck and can't do anything except manually enter the number to get bandwidth. I'm running Windows XP and don't want to use anything but batch, i.e. no VBS, Java, hybred bat, etc. If it can't be done with simple command line I'll just manually enter the number and be done with it. Here is my batch:

```
@echo off
color 0b
MODE CON:COLS=57 LINES=15
for /F "tokens=9" %%a in ('ping -n 1 -l 1024 8.8.8.8^| find "Average"') do set "A1=%%a"
echo %A1%
set /a T=%A1%
set /a varia=1000/%T%
set /a answer=%varia%
set /a varia2=%answer%
set /a answer2=%varia2%
echo.
echo    Speed %answer2% Kb/s
pause
```

and this from a answer here on stackoverflow

```
@echo off
color 0b
MODE CON:COLS=57 LINES=15
for /f "tokens=9 delims=()" %%a in (
  'ping -n 1 -l 1024 8.8.8.8^| find "Average"'
  ) do (for /f "tokens=9" %%b in ("%%a") do (
   set num=%%b & set num=!num:%%=! 
   if !num! == !num! goto nc
  )
)
:nc
echo !num!
set /a T=!num!
set /a varia=1000/%T%
set /a answer=%varia%
set /a varia2=%answer%
set /a answer2=%varia2%
echo.
echo    Speed %answer2% Kb/s
pause
```

Comment: What is it you are trying to parse?  Which bits are you interested in?  Ping isn't a good tool to measure download speed is it?

Comment: @foxidrive its more of a project to learn batch. You helped me with the netstat -e which is the better tool and it works perfectly. I'm trying to parse the average round trip time from a ping -l 1024 (1 Kb) Average = 276ms 1000/276=3.62 Kb/s Need to remove the ms after 276

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this in XP: it works in Win 8.1

```
for /F "tokens=8 delims=ms=, " %%a in ('ping -n 1 -l 1024 8.8.8.8^| find "Average" ') do set "A1=%%a"
```